# Trigger Lambda from API Gateway in Terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, triggers, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to deploy a basic API consisting in a lambda function as main endpoint and API gateway as proxy to this function. With the following configuration i'm able to build up the infrastructure, but I cannot set to trigger the lambda function through IaC, I have to go to the AWS console in order to manually set the trigger.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "main_endpoint_function" {
  function_name = "main_endpoint_function"


  s3_bucket = module.s3.function_bucket_name
  s3_key = "index.zip"


  handler = "index.handler"
  runtime = var.runtime_handler

  role = aws_iam_role.lambda_role.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda_role" {
  name = "role_lambda_test"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
//lambda has to be manually triggered from api gateway
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "apiLambda" {
  name        = "myAPI"
  description = "terraform test"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "proxy" {
   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.root_resource_id
   path_part   = "{proxy+}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxyMethod" {
   rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy.id
   http_method   = "ANY"
   authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda" {
   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.proxyMethod.resource_id
   http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.proxyMethod.http_method

   integration_http_method = "POST"
   type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
   uri                     = aws_lambda_function.main_endpoint_function.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "proxy_root" {
   rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.root_resource_id
   http_method   = "ANY"
   authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambda_root" {
   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.resource_id
   http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.http_method

   integration_http_method = "POST"
   type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
   uri                     = aws_lambda_function.main_endpoint_function.invoke_arn
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "apideploy" {
   depends_on = [
     aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda,
     aws_api_gateway_integration.lambda_root,
   ]

   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   stage_name  = "test"
}
```

Without the manually set trigger through the console I get Internal Server Error. With triggering functions correctly. Perhaps there is something wrong with my configuration ?

Update::

After adding the permission resources for Lambda and API Gateway I also created aws_api_gateway_method_response and aws_api_gateway_integration_response. On first run errors, on second run completes. I tried adding explicit implications but they didn't solve the issue..

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.http_method
  status_code = "200"
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda,
    aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy,
    aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root
  ]
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "MyDemoIntegrationResponse" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.response_200.status_code
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda,
    aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy,
    aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_root,
    aws_api_gateway_method_response.response_200
  ]

  # Transforms the backend JSON response to XML
  response_templates = {
    "application/xml" = <<EOF
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message>
    $inputRoot.body
</message>
EOF
  }
}
```

the Error is:
│ Error: Error creating API Gateway Method Response: NotFoundException: Invalid Method identifier specified
│
│   with aws_api_gateway_method_response.response_200,
│   on main.tf line 130, in resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200":
│  130: resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {

Comment: Can you drop the `depends_on` form the method that is failing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are missing the `aws_lambda_permission` resource [1]. In your case, you would need to add the following (similar to example from the reference):

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw_lambda" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.main_endpoint_function.function_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

  source_arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.myregion}:${var.accountId}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id}/*/${aws_api_gateway_method.proxyMethod.http_method}${aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy.path}"
}
```

Since I don't know which region and account you are using (I don't need to know that), you just have to replace the `var.myregion` with the API Gateway region and `var.accountId` with the AWS account where the API Gateway is created. You can achieve that by using `data` sources. In theory, you might as well leave out the method reference from the `source_arn` and use something like:

```
source_arn = "arn:aws:execute-api:${var.myregion}:${var.accountId}:${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id}/*/*/*"
```

I have removed the second reference from the code and it is now referenced in [2].

---

[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_integration#lambda-integration

[2] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've added lambda and api_gateway permissions, next issue was response integration to which I added the appropriate resource aws_api_gateway_method_response and integrated it with aws_api_gateway_integration_response and still get errors for some reason. I'll update the post..

Comment: I would say that is a different issue compared to the original one.

Comment: I totally agree

Comment: I meant to say it should be a different question, as this helped you resolve the original issue. :)